# Will 2 operating systems on 2 different drives interfere with each other?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, grub

I want to install Windows and Linux on 1 system. However, according to [this resource](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine#68587), Windows will overwrite the Grub (of Linux) during updates and Linux will overwrite the boot sector (of Windows) during updates. Will installing the 2 operating systems on different HDD's/SSD's make sure that they just can live in peace instead of constantly wrecking each other's boot partition?

Comment: If you install each system with only one disc connected, then each boot loader will be on the same disc as the OS and they will be independent. However, you will need to choose the OS from the UEFI/BIO boot selection menu. By setting the boot priority order, you can choose either OS to be the default. I have three independent OS discs configured this way in a desktop, and it works well for me.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know ,that's exactly how I would do this (install with only one disk attached each time). Do you have windows and Linux on those 3 disks? And did you performed major updates on each operating system (for example the Windows October/April updates)?

Comment: Yes to both. In fact the three OS are Win10, Ubuntu and WinXP, and the regular Win10 updates/upgrades do not affect the other boots. I haven't booted into Ubuntu for some time, and at some point I'll need to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, but I don't expect a problem, as updates within 16.04 (including grub) have previously installed fine. Note that my discs are all on-line and visible, whichever system I boot: it was only during installation that I needed to disconnect the other discs.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not going to find a "set it and forget" solution here.
If you do what you suggest you are still going to have to fiddle with BIOS boot device priority and I would not be surprised if you still got the boot loader hosed every now and then when updating.

You could also unhook the hard drive you are not using but again very fiddly.

As the question you linked states there is a fairly simple way to recover grub. If you are going to be doing dual booting it is a useful skill to acquire as grub getting hosed will happen. It is only a matter of time.

Comment: I don't mind fiddling with bios boot priority, it's quite easy and doesn't take much time. But are you sure that 2 different drives also have this issue that the bootloaders fight for it? I can understand if you try to multiboot on one drive, that they will fight for it, but if they have their own drive, I thought it would be less of a problem.

Comment: It will likely be less of a problem than on one disk but there are all kinds of corner cases and MS updates are notoriously bug-laden so that is why I am being conservative and saying you could still have issues with windows overwriting grub even with two disks. I still think having grub recovery in your bag of tricks will be a good thing for trying to boot both OS's.

Comment: Will this be an issue with bitlocker and encrypted disk (linux)?

Comment: Honestly not tried it. In general I always discourage dual booting. In my experience it is more trouble than it is worth. My advice is boot whichever OS you need to use more and run the rest in VM's.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all of the time.  My current box is running Windows 10 and Debian9 on the same drive.  The secret here is to figure out the partition scheme ahead of time and install Windows first.  Linux installs seem to play nicely these days.

The GRUB (or GRUB2) installers will add your windows partition to the grub boot and your will be able to choose which one you want.

IF you install windows 2nd, it will be a pain in the butt as Windows will wipe the MBR with it's own boot loader.  Getting grub back is a pain in the rear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can play nicely. For this you need to install Windows in one of the drive first as usual. Then install linux in the second drive, this is where grub is going to "live". I have had Windows 10 and Xunbuntu for more than a year without hiccups on boot, even with updates on both systems. I can't say the same about Windows itlsef with the "creators update" oh the horror.

This is what I have on my ultrabook Linux on a 32gb M1 drive and Windows 7 on a 512gb SSD. And I have this on my desktop, Linux on a 512 gb hhd and Windows 10 on a 512 SSD.

A perk is that if you disconnect the drive containing linux, your rig will boot to Windows by default. If you disconnect your Windows drive, you will se an entry on grub for it. If you choose it, it error and reboot.

For a one drive solution check @SeñorCMasMas(lol) answer.

Cheers.